# connection strategy between PHP and android app

Tags: android, html

Me and my friends are working on some app where we are displaying HTML5 games (built by construct) and we want to target when user lose. The best way I think to implement this connectivity is by sending the HTML5 construct game HTTP request with user id parameter, when the HTML5 object targets lose it will send HTTP request to a web service with the total score and the user id it got from the previous request. Unfortunately, now I don't know how the app will target the lose. I think I am missing something or my strategy isn't good. I would love to get some ideas and tips for better way to implement this.

Comment: `and we want to target when user lose.` ??? What would that be?

Comment: we are targeting for lose by using built in construct functions so that is not a problem.